# Intellij "cannot resolve symbol" in two-letter package name

Tags: java, intellij-idea

haven't been able to find any info specific to what I'm seeing.

My main package is `re.dice`under which all my code is held.

IntelliJ is currently highlighting the two-letter portion `re` in red, displaying the error message "*Cannot resolve symbol "re"*".

My project builds correctly in Maven and I haven't yet implemented any functionality in the class to see if there are any further problems.

Is this a bug in IntelliJ? Or are two-letter package names problematic? I cannot see that it's reserved for anything - I wonder if it's just a setting somewhere that I need to make IntelliJ aware of?

**EDIT** Here is my configuration class

```
package re.dice.config;

import freemarker.template.utility.XmlEscape;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.*;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.freemarker.FreeMarkerConfigurer;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan("re.dice")
@EnableWebMvc
public class AppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean(name = "freemarkerConfig")
    public FreeMarkerConfigurer freemarkerConfig() {
        FreeMarkerConfigurer configurer = new FreeMarkerConfigurer();
        configurer.setTemplateLoaderPath("/templates");
        Map<String,Object> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("xml_escape", new XmlEscape());
        configurer.setFreemarkerVariables(map);
        return configurer;
    }

    @Override
    public void configureContentNegotiation(ContentNegotiationConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.ignoreUnknownPathExtensions(false).defaultContentType(MediaType.TEXT_HTML);
    }

    @Override
    public void configureViewResolvers(ViewResolverRegistry registry) {
        registry.freeMarker();
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(final ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/css/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/css/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources");
    }
}
```

And here is my `pom.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>re.dice</groupId>
    <artifactId>frontend</artifactId>
    <name>frontend</name>
    <version>0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.0.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-freemarker</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

This is the only project that I currently have which is under this package name.

With hindsight - I realise this is not a "bug" with IntelliJ but rather a "peculiarity" maybe.

Comment: Intellij Idea has no problems with 2-character package names, even 1-char names are fine. Looks like you have problems with classpath configuration. But you haven't posted any code or config files, so it's really hard to realize what is the cause

Comment: Not a bug in IntelliJ.  I'm certain it's your code/configuration.

Comment: I have one suggestion. Package `re.dice` is a part of another maven project written by you. And you're trying to refer if from different maven project. In such case make sure you have installed project containing `re.dice` into your local maven repo. Run `mvn clean install` on project containing `re.dice`, then do the same for your project that refers `re.dice`

Comment: Side note: we have a really huge code base; with a lot of "exotic" "unconventional" stuff in it ... things work fine with eclipse; but our first (maybe naive) approach to build with IntelliJ failed; and if I remember correctly, because IntelliJ didn't "accept" one of our packages that had ".rcs." in it. So, maybe it is a just a configuration problem; but keep the "bug in IntelliJ" idea around ;-)

Comment: Please show a code fragment where intellij is highlighting an error. by the way I use 2 letter package names all the time, `no.xyz` for Norway domains... and it works fine in intellij

Comment: It sounds like your source root isn't configured properly. Are you sure intellij is recognising this as a java file??

Answer (score 0):

`re.dice` means that you have two packages inside which are `re` and `dice`. And `dice` folder is inside the `re` folder.

You can create folder `re` in your project file and put `dice` inside it; or, the smartest one, you can change your package name like "`re_dice`" or something else like that. You shouldn't use '.'s when you are giving names to your files.

Comment: This actually made me realise that the package name had been created as `re.dice` and not two separate folders as I had previously thought.

IntelliJ seems a bit funny when dragging and dropping packages into one another to reorganise.

For example - creating a package folder `dice` under `re` then dragging the package `config` into it, effectively renames it to `dice.re`.

I solved this by dragging all of the packages I wanted to move at the same time - this preserved the package structure that I was looking for.